# getPersistentRDDs returns Map of cached RDDs and DataFrames in Spark 2.2.0, but in Spark 2.4.7 - it returns Map of cached RDDs only

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

If cache RDD and DataFrame in Spark version 2.2.0 `getPersistentRDDs` returns Map size 2:

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(1))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(2)).toDF
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: int]

scala> spark.sparkContext.getPersistentRDDs
res0: scala.collection.Map[Int,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_]] = Map()

scala> df.cache
res1: df.type = [value: int]

scala> spark.sparkContext.getPersistentRDDs
res2: scala.collection.Map[Int,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_]] =
Map(4 -> *SerializeFromObject [input[0, int, false] AS value#2]
+- Scan ExternalRDDScan[obj#1]
 MapPartitionsRDD[4] at cache at <console>:27)

scala> rdd.cache
res3: rdd.type = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> spark.sparkContext.getPersistentRDDs
res4: scala.collection.Map[Int,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_]] =
Map(0 -> ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:24, 4 -> *SerializeFromObject [input[0, int, false] AS value#2]
+- Scan ExternalRDDScan[obj#1]
 MapPartitionsRDD[4] at cache at <console>:27)
```

but in Spark version 2.4.7 `getPersistentRDDs` returns Map size 1

```
...
scala> spark.sparkContext.getPersistentRDDs
res4: scala.collection.Map[Int,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_]] = Map(0 -> ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:24)
```

And the question how to get all cached objects not just RDDs
and what suddenly happened to the method that began to behave differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataframe is not actually cached in memory because no action has been performed on the dataframe yet, so it's actually fair to exclude it from the result of `getPersistentRDDs`. I think the behaviour in the later version is actually desirable. But once you have done something on the dataframe, **it will be cached**, and it will appear in the result of `getPersistentRDDs`, as shown below:

```
scala> val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(2)).toDF
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: int]

scala> sc.getPersistentRDDs
res0: scala.collection.Map[Int,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_]] = Map()

scala> df.cache
res1: df.type = [value: int]

scala> sc.getPersistentRDDs
res2: scala.collection.Map[Int,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_]] = Map()

scala> df.count()
res3: Long = 1

scala> sc.getPersistentRDDs
res4: scala.collection.Map[Int,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_]] =
Map(3 -> *(1) SerializeFromObject [input[0, int, false] AS value#2]
+- Scan[obj#1]
 MapPartitionsRDD[3] at count at <console>:26)
```

Comment: Thanks. Looking at the behavior of the method, I completely forgot that DFs and DSs get into the cache after executing any action. From my point of view, the semantics of this method is very ambivalent, as many things in Spark. It would be nice to have two methods one returns a list of all DSs, RDDs and DFs that will be cached and second returns that are already cached.